# How this kind sequence do faults in different algorithms

Tags: operating-system

Consider the following memory reference string: 0,6,5,1,4,5,0,5,3,6,5,5,2,3,2,3,5,2,2,6.
Assuming that we have four page frames, show the contents of the page frames after each
reference, using (A) OPTIMAL, (B) FIFO and (C) LRU

Answer (score 0):

Is this an examination or assignment problem?

Does B explicitly wait until A relinquishes the CPU; or is B simply desiring the CPU which it cannot acquire until A is done with it?

When B decides to wait, what is it waiting for?  A to run again?  Is this some sort of hidden relationship?

When 4/10 is compared to 3/10,  3/10 is chosen; why do you think that is?  A disdain for even numbers?

The scheduling algorithm appears to prefer smaller numbers; there is no mention of IO anywhere in this, so that must be a misdirection; thus neither.

Because the question is poorly poised.

Yes, every scheduling algorithm can result in starvation, otherwise you wouldn't need a scheduling algorithm.  What are they teaching these days?

If you could support the answers above, they would provide you with the necessary framework to pass your class.  Without the support, your professor will think you a fool.  Rest assured; the questions are as foolish as the answers, you will be in no worse a place than your professor.